# Is there a reliable way to get the MediaStore asset from a image picker URL

Tags: android, flutter, mediastore

When using the [default photo picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker), one only receives an URL to the image or video.

I would like to also get some [Media Store](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) metadata, but am not sure if there is a way to get the media store asset from the url.

How would I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this could be a reliable solution:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {imageURL};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
    // Do something with the image ID.
}

if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.close();
}
```